# How to MYSQL get data group by every hour in 24 hours even data if not present , IF 0 will select NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

For Example DATA and Query Avail on This LINK SQL FIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13aec/23

Comment: 1) Show desured result for your fiddle. 2) Does your MySQL version (on your production server) is really 5.6?

Comment: Hai @Akina yes is 5.6

Comment: *yes is 5.6* If so - no way, the hours table must be generated... but I'd recommend to create a static table with the numbers from 0 to 23 - this would allow not to write long generating code in each query...

Comment: Yes, Thanks for suggestion @Akina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
LEFT JOIN place_rvw ON jam.za_hour = HOUR(time) 
                   AND place_rvw.time between '2014-02-17' AND '2014-02-19'
```

WHERE clause must be removed at all.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13aec/38)

PS. I'd recommend to use `place_rvw.time >= '2014-02-17' AND place_rvw.time < '2014-02-19'`. [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13aec/39). The reason - if the data for `'2014-02-19 00:00:00'` is present it will be included while using BETWEEN.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your `where` clause because it is filtering out null records:

```
where place_rvw.time between '2014-02-17' AND '2014-02-19'
or place_rvw.place_id is null
```

Updated SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13aec/27

You can also achieve the desired result by modifying the `left join` condition as others have pointed out, but I prefer the `where` clause.

The date filter (`place_rvw.time between '2014-02-17' AND '2014-02-19'`) isn't really a condition that is *needed* to join the two tables, but it is just a data filter, so it should be in the `where` clause.

Comment: @MiftachHidayatullah you are welcome. You can also achieve the desired result by modifying the `left join` condition, but I prefer the `where` clause. The date filter (`place_rvw.time between '2014-02-17' AND '2014-02-19'`) isn't really a condition that is needed to join the two tables, but it is just a data filter, so it should belong in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incorrect

```
SELECT 
  jam.za_hour as `hour`, 
  AVG(IFNULL(place_id,0)) as average_score
FROM (
  SELECT 0 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 1 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 2 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 3 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 4 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 5 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 6 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 7 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 8 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 9 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 10 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 11 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 12 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 13 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 14 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 15 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 16 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 17 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 18 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 19 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 20 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 21 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 22 as za_hour
  UNION
  SELECT 23 as za_hour
) jam
LEFT OUTER JOIN place_rvw  ON (jam.za_hour = HOUR(time) AND (DATE(time) BETWEEN '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-28'))

GROUP BY
  jam.za_hour

ORDER BY jam.za_hour;

select * from place_rvw
```

If you use between in where condition it weed out everything else, you need to add this condition in the on condition.